# Sobolev embedding theorem one dimension

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

In the proof given by Haim Brezis that $ W ^{1,p} $ to $L ^ \infty $  is a continuous injection, he first proves the injection for compactly supported continuously differentiable functions and then concludes by density argument. 
However, this result only gives that $u_n$ converges to $u$ in $W^{1,p}$ and $u_n$ converges to some function say $g$ in $L^ \infty$

How can we conclude from this that $u = g$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $u_n \to u$ in $W^{1,p}$ we have in particular that $u_n \to u$ in $L^p$, so an even weaker statement is that $u_n \to u$ in measure.  Likewise, $L^\infty$ convergence also implies convergence in measure, so $u_n \to g$ in measure.  But limits in measure are unique up to null sets, so $u=g$ a.e.